# How can i use a backend pre-signed url to upload files to Amazon S3 using its SDK?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

I have a Rails backend and it returns to me a "signature" string, "objectKey" string and a "policy" string. I have to use these parameters to upload the file selected by the user, but i don't find any way to use these parameters instead of the "accessKey" and the "accessSecretKey" using the Amazon JavaScript SDK.

I already have a code that make the upload, but it is using the credentials directly, and it doesn't looks safe.

Anyone already faced this problem?

Comment: You need to add a CORS policy to your bucket. That will enable other operations using signature on your bucket.

Comment: @datasage Hi. The bucket already have CORS. The main problem is that i can't use my credentials(access key and access secret key) directly on frontend - I'm using it on development time, and it is working.. There is an json payload sent from my backend that gives me a signature, a policy hash and a object key to the file. These parameters are generated by backend using Rails sdk. Is it enough to send the file using S3 Javascript sdk? I don't know how to send the files from frontend without the secret key.

Comment: Yes, all you need is the access key and the signature you have generated. Take a look at this sample:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

Comment: @datasage But i can't see any place to insert the signature or another item of my payload using the aws sdk for JavaScript. It's necessary to use a form or a simple xmlhttprequest instead of Aws Sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not found a solution for my problem with AWS Sdk for JavaScript.

Looks that, in our case, the workflow(signature/policy generation) is the same of the shown in this article https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

To solve this problem I replaced the Sdk to a simple XmlHttpRequest and a FormData object to push my files to s3. The payload could not be changed to keep compatibility with another parts of the app. Using this approach it's necessary to have an AccessKey, policy, signature, key(file key) and the file in the formData. Depending on how the policy/signature was generated, it's also necessary to add other fields to formData to get the things working. In this case, i've added a sucess_action_status.

The code to mount the formData:

```
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('key', <KEY>);
  formData.append('AWSAccessKeyId', <ACCESS_KEY>);
  formData.append('policy', <POLICY>);
  formData.append('signature', <SIGNATURE>);
  formData.append('success_action_status', <SUCCESS_CODE>);
  formData.append('file', file, file.name);
```

With this form data, create a XMLHttpRequest like this

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST","https://<YOUR BUCKET>.s3.amazonaws.com");
request.setRequestHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

And send the request passing the formData object.

```
request.send(formData);
```

It's important to remember that the values in formData must respect the generated policy.

It's possible to get the upload process by adding this Listener:

```
request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
      console.log(e);
});
```

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can not upload an object with a presigned url. AWS has the solution in order to grant temporary credentials called AWS Security Token Service. The short name is AWS STS.

[Requesting Temporary Security Credentials - AWS Identity and Access Management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html)

For examples:

1. An user accesses to your rails application.
2. Your rails application issues and returns a temporary credentials using AWS STS.

   ```
   client = Aws::STS::Client.new
   policy = AWS::STS::Policy.new do |p|
     p.allow(
       actions: ['s3:PutObject'],
       resources: ['arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket/path/to/xxx*'],
       effect: 'allow'
     )
   end

   token = client.get_federation_token(name: 'name', policy: policy.to_json, duration_seconds: 900)
   puts token.credentials.to_json
   # {
   #   "access_key_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   #   "secret_access_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   #   "session_token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   #   "expiration": "2016-03-25T00:46:20Z"
   # }
   ```
3. The user upload an object securely using the temporary credentials.

Note that when you use the temporary credentials, you have to authenticate with access_key_id, secret_access_key and **session_token**.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But, currently, i can't change my backend code to generate the acces key id, secret access key and session token... If these parameters are really mandatory, i must tell the backend devs to provite them in the payload.

Comment: So far as I know, this solution is the only way for users upload a file securely from browsers. I hope that the backend devs develop it. Good luck!

Comment: "You can not upload an object with a presigned url". The folowing article, "Uploading Objects Using Pre-Signed URLs" suggest differently: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html, although I have not tested it myself.